# Error on creating conditional column in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, subset, calculated-columns

Thank you for your kind responses. I have a dataframe and I need to apply a formula over a columns depending of the value of other column:

```
data <- data.frame(figure = c("square","square","circle","square","circle"),
                   diameter =c(NA,NA,21,NA,12),
                   side=c(32,27,NA,51,NA))
```

What I need is to calculate the area according the square or circle formula (square = side * side, circle= pi*(diameter/2)^2) in a new column:

```
data$area <- 0
data$area[data$figure == "square"] <- data$side*data$side
data$area[data$figure == "circle"] <- pi*(data$diameter/2)^2
```

But when I calculate this way, I get the last formula and the following error:

> The number of items to replace is not a multiple of the length of the replacement.

I suposse this could be related with column selection in brackets. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `ifelse`

```
data$area <- with(data, ifelse(figure == "square", side^2, pi*(diameter/2)^2))
```

---

The lhs and rhs should have the same length.  In the OP's code, the `lhs` is of different length than the rhs (i.e. full column values are used in rhs) i.e.

```
data$area[data$figure == "square"] <- (data$side*data$side)[data$figure == "square"]
data$area[data$figure == "circle"] <- (pi*(data$diameter/2)^2)[data$figure == "circle"]
```

-output

```
> data
  figure diameter side      area
1 square       NA   32 1024.0000
2 square       NA   27  729.0000
3 circle       21   NA  346.3606
4 square       NA   51 2601.0000
5 circle       12   NA  113.0973
```